# Taylor polynomials respect derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, taylor-expansion

> I want to prove that the derivative of the $n$th order Taylor polynomial is the $n-1$th order Taylor polynomial of the derivative. More specifically:

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $n$ times differentiable about $x_0$ and $T_n(x)$ a polynomail of degree at most $n$.
Then if
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x) - T_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}
= 0
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x) - T'_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}
= 0
$$

$\textbf{I am looking for a proof of this fact that is as direct as possible}$. The fact looks like a simple corollary of l'hopitals rule. However I don't think this is legitimate since l'hopitals rule assumes that the limit $\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists, and this is what we are trying to prove.

I think this property should be true by the following argument:
The hypothesis implies $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th order Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $x_0$.
Hence
$$
T_n(x)
= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k.
$$
This implies $$T'_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k+1)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{g^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$$

where $g(x) = f'(x)$. Hence $T'_n(x)$ is the $n-1$th order Taylor polynomial of $g(x) = f'(x)$. Again it is well known that this implies $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x) - T'_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n-1}} = 0$$

Comment: The logic of your argument is correct, and as long as you're able to justify the first equal sign in the computation of $T_n'(x)$, your proof is correct. Also, I think your argument is already pretty direct. The only "indirect" parts of your proof are the fact that given a function $g$, the $n^{th}$ order taylor polynomial about $x_0$ for $g$, denoted by $P_{n,x_0,g}$ is the UNIQUE polynomial of degree $\leq n$ which equals $g$ up to order $n$ at $x_0$. (You made use of this twice, once to conclude $T_n$ is the taylor polynomial for $f$, and at the end to conclude the limit for $T_n'$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think that the statement of the theorem is very simple yet its proof uses Taylors theorem which is "large" enough that I would like to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true as stated. Take $n=1$. Then if $T_1=a+b(x-x_0)$, the first condition just means that $f(x_0)=a$ and $f'(x_0)=b$. From that, you want to conclude that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)=b$, i. e. that $f'$ is continuous at $x_0$. But there are differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives, e. g. $x^2\sin(1/x)$, extended to be $0$ at $x=0$.

If $n>1$, then your proof is fine. The catch is that to apply Taylor's theorem to $g$, you need $n-1\geq 1.$ (or you can extend it to polynomials of degree 0 is you define a 0 times differentiable function to be a continuous function, but then it is not true that a derivative of an $n$ times differentiable function is $n-1$ times differentiable).